# how to show alert dialog on top of any activity in an application android

Tags: android

I want to display an alert dialog. And this alert dialog is created in one activity. But Problem is i want to display this dialog on top of any activity in an application when i get some response from server

Comment: pass application context for your alert dialogue. It will be displayed on top of any activity .

Comment: Passing the application context can result in "WindwoManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes i got the solution....

first i created a class for displaying alert dialog.
upon receiving a response from server calling a method to display alert dialog by passing application context

```
package io.omoto.omotokairaliapp.Utls;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.gitonway.lee.niftymodaldialogeffects.lib.NiftyDialogBuilder;

import io.omoto.omotokairaliapp.Constants.Constants;

/**
 * Created by ${venkie} on ${28/1/16}.
 */
public class DisplayRegisteredMessage {

    Context context;
    private NiftyDialogBuilder dialogBuilder;


    public DisplayRegisteredMessage(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    public void displayMessage() {

        if (Constants.FLAG == 1) {
            Constants.FLAG = 0;

            dialogBuilder = NiftyDialogBuilder.getInstance(context);
            dialogBuilder
                    .withTitle("Response is already registered")
                    .withMessage("For this Customer we have already taken response Sorry!!");
            dialogBuilder.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            dialogBuilder.show();

        } else {


        }
    }


}
```

The above code displays alert dialog

```
@Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                Log.e("response page", response.toString());
                try {
                    if (response.getString(Constants.STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"))
                        p7.deleterecord(p7b.getFlowid());
                        p7.deleteRows();

                    Constants.FLAG = 1;
                    DisplayRegisteredMessage displayRegisteredMessage = new DisplayRegisteredMessage(mContext);
                    displayRegisteredMessage.displayMessage();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.e("Page 6", p7b.getFlowid());
            }
```

Comment: Is mContext the application context or something else?  If something else, how did you get it?  If the application context, how did you avoid the WindwoManager$BadTokenException?

Answer (score 0):

Create alert dialog in other class (not activity) as shown below code in static method & call this method using UDF.showAlertDialog(activity) where you want to show dialog.

```
public class UDF { 
public static void showAlertDialog(
                String warning,
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveClickListener,
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeClickListener,
                Context context) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertdialog.setMessage(warning);

            alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", positiveClickListener);
            alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", negativeClickListener);
            alertdialog.show();

        }

    }
```

Edit : set this

```
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

and add permission in menifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

& pass `getApplicationContext()` while creating dialog instade of activity or context

Comment: The problem is i have an broadcast receiver in my application it keeps on checking whether device is connected to internet..if internet is available am trying to send some records to server...based on response i received from server i want show alert dialog.. The challenge is if am in an activity in which alert dialog is created...at that time it displays dialog perfectly..but if i moved some other activity it throws an exception saying Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application android

Comment: what r u passing activity or context while creating dialog?

Comment: am passing application context... It works .....but when i turn off my internet and move to next activity and again i turned on internet at that it throws null pointer exception..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that worked for me:

Suppose you have 4 activities in total:

1. MainActivity
2. OtherActivity1
3. OtherActivity2
4. OtherActivity3

I had the code for the alert dialog in the MainActivity and I wanted the alert dialog to display in all activities. I did the following:

1. Make other activities extend the main activity.

   ```
   public class OtherActivity1 extends MainActivity{

   }

   public class OtherActivity2 extends MainActivity{

   }

   public class OtherActivity3 extends MainActivity{

   }
   ```

In your Main activity, save the context in a variable.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static Context contextMain;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        contextMain = MainActivity.this;

    }

}
```

And wherever you are trying to call your alert dialog in the MainActivity just pass contextMain as the context.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(contextMain)
```